# How do I call the Python's list while debugging?

Tags: python, debugging

I have the following python code:

```
values = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

I run the script and I am in the debugging shell:

```
(pdb) list(values)
*** Error in argument: '(values)'
(Pdb)
```

How can I call `list(values)` in the debugger without invoking the debugger's own `list` command?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Just `print` it:

```
(Pdb) print list(values)
```

don't foget to add brackets for python3 version

```
(Pdb) print(list(values))
```

Comment: `p` and `pp` is shorter to type =)

Comment: Why does this happens?

Comment: @Sebastialonso list is a pdb command that prints the src code using ! to escape it via `!list` makes pdb know that you're not running a pdb command

Answer (score 109):

Use the exclamation mark ! to escape debugger commands:

```
(Pdb) values = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
(Pdb) list(values)
*** Error in argument: '(values)'
(Pdb) !list(values)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it allows me to actually use the list when debugging

Comment: I didn't even realize it was `pdb` messing this up. Awesome, thanks!

Comment: This confused me for like 2 hours. o_O pdb intercepting python built-ins is so cringe.

Answer (score 4):

Enter "Interactive Mode" by typing `interact`.

```py
(Pdb) heros = ['Gecko', 'Catboy', 'Owlette']
(Pdb) list(heros)
*** Error in argument: '(heros)'
(Pdb) interact
*interactive*
>>> list(heros)
['Gecko', 'Catboy', 'Owlette']
```

"Interactive Mode" also lets you address variables whose name conflict with PDB commands.

Answer (score 1):

Thierry,

Since this data structure is already an sequence it is redundant to specify it as a list. So this will work fine.

```
(Pdb) print values
```

or

```
(Pbd) print(values)
```

if you are using Python3

---

Optionally for a nice listing with newlines

```
(Pdb) for x in values:  print x
```

or

```
(Pdb) for x in values:  print(x)
```

for Python3

Comment: But it isn't a `list`, it is a `set`.

Comment: A `set` is not an `array`... you are still thinking about a `list`

Comment: I trust this explanation is true?

Comment: You don't need to classify it as anything else except for what it is, a `set`. I think what you mean to say is that if you just want to look at the values you can just print it.

Comment: Thats fine, but the list(set) is not needed, it is important to note that.

Comment: I wanted to do a sorted operation in the debugger and I could only do that with an iterable, which is why I wanted to convert it into a list.  I could have used a list comprehension but didn't feel like typing too much for a simple sorted operation.

Answer (score 0):

Another somewhat hackerish way to do it is type:

```
lst=list
```

at the `pdb` prompt. Next you can write:

```
values = set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
lst(values)
```

Obviously this is not the recommended answer.