# Why does casting dict_keys as a list not work in pdb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, pdb

Following the canonical advice of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322668/typeerror-dict-keys-object-does-not-support-indexing), I am trying to cast my `dict_keys` object to a list.  It works in the python 3.6.5 interpreter just fine.  However, when I do it in `pdb`, it does not work.  E.g.

```
>>> import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
--Return--
<function save_history at 0x100369e18>
> <stdin>(1)<module>()->None
(Pdb) newdict = dict()
(Pdb) newdict["pig"] = "pink"
(Pdb) newdict["finch"] = "yellow"
(Pdb) newdict.keys()
dict_keys(['pig', 'finch'])
(Pdb) list(newdict.keys())
*** Error in argument: '(newdict.keys())'
```

How do I get this to work in `pdb`?

Comment: Not a duplicate. See edit.

Comment: python 3 just add brackets `print(list(newdict.keys()))` and look on the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12084184/8060120)

Comment: Ok. That does work

Answer (score 4):

`list` is a pdb command to list source code for the file:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-list

To escape the pdb command, you can call it like this:

```
(Pdb) !list(newdict.keys())
```